# How to create a glass textue with streaks

Tags: rendering, texturing, glass

Inspired by Daniel Krafft on YouTube, I wanted to remake the League of Legends Icon with a somewhat 3D look with glass in the middle. (Replacing the blue, streaky part in the middle.) So far I looked on a couple of texture websites but can't really find anything close. I've also tried to use glass shader and color ith using a wave node with a color ramp. Unfortunately, that doesn't really achive the look I want. I appreciate any ideas, but please keep in mind that im really new to Blender and likely wont understand too advanced texturing stuff :).
Thanks[image: Thats the icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a mix between 2 textures like a *Musgrave Texture* and a *Noise Texture* that are used as factor between an *Emission* and a *Transparent* node. In *Eevee* don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* in the *Material* panel > *Settings*.

[image]